# Why is the Write-Host message printing after a return statement in a function?

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following function to attempt to start the Sql Server agent service if it isn't currently running:

```
function Start-SqlAgent([string] $AgentServiceName)
{
    $agentService = Get-Service -Name $AgentServiceName

    if ($AgentServiceName.Status -eq "Running")
    {
        Write-Host "$AgentServiceName is running"
        return
    }

    Write-Host "Starting $AgentServiceName..."
    # Code that starts the service below here (unrelated to my question)
}
```

When the Sql Agent service is running and I call the function like this:

```
Write-Host "Checking SQL Agent service status..."
Start-SqlAgent -AgentServiceName "SQLSERVERAGENT"
```

I get the following output:

> Checking SQL Agent service status...
>
> Starting SQLSERVERAGENT...

Why is the `Starting SQLSERVERAGENT...` message displayed? The output I would expect is:

> Checking SQL Agent service status...
>
> SQLSERVERAGENT is running

Comment: Your `if` statement is failing, obviously.  That's all we can tell you for certain based on your question.  Make sure the servicename is actually `sqlserveragent` and that you're not actually referencing the displayname.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because **`$AgentServiceName`** is a string. What you need to check against is **`$agentService`**.

```
$agentService = Get-Service -Name $AgentServiceName

if ($agentService.Status -eq "Running")
{
    Write-Host "$AgentServiceName is running"
    return
}

Write-Host "Starting $AgentServiceName..."
```

Comment: Holy crap I'm dumb. I knew it was something simple like this that I wasn't seeing. Thank you. I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @LewsTherin Typos happen.  Should write a PSSA rule for referenced, undefined variables!

Comment: FWIW, an advanced editor like Visual Studio Code will tell you that `$agentService` is unused. That's the only editor I use for PowerShell these days.